# How do I enable 3d acceleration on an APU?

Tags: bejeweled-3

I am unable to check High (1024x768) or Ultra (1920x1200) because "Resolution Error" : "3D acceleration must be enabled to switch to a higher resolution."

I am unable to check 3D Acceleration because "Not Supported" : "3D acceleration cannot be enabled on this computer.  Your video card does not meet the minimum requirements for this game."

I am using an A10-7850K APU on Windows 8.1 - I have no video card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upping the resolution on my main monitor from 1400x900 to 1680x1050 causes the game to enable hardware acceleration mode, unlocking all the options.